# Getting the name of the page via PHP?

Tags: php

Say I'm at:

```
http://www.somewhere.com/pages/plants.php?pageid=13
```

I know how to get the pageid via _GET but how would I get '/pages/plants.php' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable

In fact, check out the entire `$_SERVER` array for a ton of interesting values about the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Do a `print_r($_SERVER)` for more values.

Comment: The REQUEST_URI value, from what I understand, only works on Apache machines. This wouldn't work on PHP on an IIS box.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

That should get you the path after the address :)

Answer (score 0):

Use variables available in `$_SERVER`, and use `parse_url()` to get the needed part.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] // path 

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] // domain
```